# Row positions relative to a specific condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with "Athletes" playing "Matches" ("Match"==1) on random "Dates". For example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 80, ncol = 5))
colnames(df) <- c("Athlete", "Date", "Match", "DaysAfter", "DaysBefore")
df[,"Athlete"] <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2,20), rep(3, 20), rep(4, 20))
df[,"Date"] <- rep(1:20, 4)
df[,"Match"] <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
```

I want to make two variables:

```
df$DaysAfter <- # number of days after last "Match" (for each "Athlete").
df$DaysBefore <- # number of days before next "Match" (for each "Athlete").
```

PS! When "Match" == 1, then "DaysAfter"  and  "DaysBefore" should be 0. 
When there are no matches before in "DaysAfter"  and after in "DaysBefore", show NA (see example).

I want the dataset to look like this:

```
Ath Dat Mat DA  DB
1   1   0   NA  -4
1   2   0   NA  -3
1   3   0   NA  -2
1   4   0   NA  -1
1   5   1   0   0
1   6   0   1   -2
1   7   0   2   -1
1   8   1   0   0
1   9   0   1   -4
1   10  0   2   -3
1   11  0   3   -2
1   12  0   4   -1
1   13  1   0   0
1   14  0   1   -2
1   15  0   2   -1
1   16  1   0   0
1   17  0   1   NA
1   18  0   2   NA
1   19  0   3   NA
1   20  0   4   NA
2   1   0   NA  -4
2   2   0   NA  -3
etc.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Athlete' and another grouping variable created based on the position of 1 in 'Match' (`cumsum(Match == 1)`), we create two columns -

1) DA - As we need `NA` for all the elements until the first 1 in 'Match', create a logical condition with `if/else` so that `all` the elements that are 0 in 'Match' will be multiplied by 'NA' (NA* any number returns NA).  As we did the grouping by `cumsum`, only the first group have all elements as 0, so that part got solved.  The `else` condition gets the sequence of rows and subtract 1 from it (`.seq_len(.N)-1).

2) DB - We multiply the 'Match' with the number of rows (`.N`) and subtract from the reverse sequence (`.N:1`).  Once we get this done, the last part involves creating NA for the elements in the column after the last 1 in 'Match'.  Grouped by 'Athlete', we get the row index (`.I`) of the sequence from the last 1 in 'Match' (next element) to the number of rows (`.N`), and assign (`:=`) the 'DB' to NA based on that index.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df)[, c("DA", "DB") := list(if(all(!Match)) NA*Match else 
   seq_len(.N)-1,Match*(.N) -(.N:1)) , by = .(cumsum(Match==1), Athlete)]
df1[df1[,  .I[(max(which(Match==1))+1):.N] , by = Athlete]$V1,  DB:= NA][]
#    Athlete Date Match DA DB
# 1:       1    1     0 NA -4
# 2:       1    2     0 NA -3
# 3:       1    3     0 NA -2
# 4:       1    4     0 NA -1
# 5:       1    5     1  0  0
# 6:       1    6     0  1 -2
# 7:       1    7     0  2 -1
# 8:       1    8     1  0  0
# 9:       1    9     0  1 -6
#10:       1   10     0  2 -5
#11:       1   11     0  3 -4
#12:       1   12     0  4 -3
#13:       1   13     0  5 -2
#14:       1   14     0  6 -1
#15:       1   15     1  0  0
#16:       1   16     0  1 -2
#17:       1   17     0  2 -1
#18:       1   18     1  0  0
#19:       1   19     0  1 NA
#20:       1   20     0  2 NA
#21:       2    1     0 NA -4
#22:       2    2     0 NA -3
#23:       2    3     0 NA -2
#24:       2    4     0 NA -1
#25:       2    5     1  0  0
#26:       2    6     0  1 -2
#27:       2    7     0  2 -1
#28:       2    8     1  0  0
#29:       2    9     0  1 -6
#30:       2   10     0  2 -5
#31:       2   11     0  3 -4
#32:       2   12     0  4 -3
#33:       2   13     0  5 -2
#34:       2   14     0  6 -1
#35:       2   15     1  0  0
#36:       2   16     0  1 -2
#37:       2   17     0  2 -1
#38:       2   18     1  0  0
#39:       2   19     0  1 NA
#40:       2   20     0  2 NA
#41:       3    1     0 NA -4
#42:       3    2     0 NA -3
#43:       3    3     0 NA -2
#44:       3    4     0 NA -1
#45:       3    5     1  0  0
#46:       3    6     0  1 -2
#47:       3    7     0  2 -1
#48:       3    8     1  0  0
#49:       3    9     0  1 -6
#50:       3   10     0  2 -5
#51:       3   11     0  3 -4
#52:       3   12     0  4 -3
#53:       3   13     0  5 -2
#54:       3   14     0  6 -1
#55:       3   15     1  0  0
#56:       3   16     0  1 -2
#57:       3   17     0  2 -1
#58:       3   18     1  0  0
#59:       3   19     0  1 NA
#60:       3   20     0  2 NA
#61:       4    1     0 NA -4
#62:       4    2     0 NA -3
#63:       4    3     0 NA -2
#64:       4    4     0 NA -1
#65:       4    5     1  0  0
#66:       4    6     0  1 -2
#67:       4    7     0  2 -1
#68:       4    8     1  0  0
#69:       4    9     0  1 -6
#70:       4   10     0  2 -5
#71:       4   11     0  3 -4
#72:       4   12     0  4 -3
#73:       4   13     0  5 -2
#74:       4   14     0  6 -1
#75:       4   15     1  0  0
#76:       4   16     0  1 -2
#77:       4   17     0  2 -1
#78:       4   18     1  0  0
#79:       4   19     0  1 NA
#80:       4   20     0  2 NA
```

Comment: This does not exactly show the wished result. Line 19 and 20 have a wrong result. NA would be correct

19:       1   19     0         1         NA  1 -2
20:       1   20     0         2         NA  2 -1
21:       2    1     0        NA         -4 NA -4
22:       2    2     0        NA         -3 NA -3

Comment: @Otto_K Can you please confirm whether the output updated is correct

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
   unique_list<-(unique(df$Athlete))
for(k in (1:length(unique_list))){
index<-c(1:dim(df)[1])[df$Athlete==unique_list[k]]
count=NA
for(j in index){
  if(df$Mat[j]==1){
       count=0
      }else{
  count=count+1
  }
  df$DaysAfter[j]=count
  }
  count=NA
  for(j in index[c(length(index):1)]){
  if(df$Mat[j]==1){
       count=0
      }else{
  count=count-1
  }
  df$DaysBefore[j]=count
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's almost right. I need the code to be run separately for every Athlete so that there is no overlapping between athletes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote the following function:

```
cumsum.r <- function (vals, restart) 
{
    if (!is.vector(vals) || !is.vector(restart)) 
        stop("expect vectors")
    if (length(vals) != length(restart)) 
        stop("different length")
    len = length(vals)
    restart[1] = T
    ind = which(restart)
    ind = rep(ind, c(ind[-1], len + 1) - ind)
    vals.c = cumsum(vals)
    vals.c - vals.c[ind] + vals[ind]
}
```

It performs cumsum, but starts from zero whenever restart=TRUE.

For "days after", you need

```
new.ath <- c(TRUE, df$Ath[-1]==df$Ath[-length(df$Ath)])
restart <- df$Math==1 |  new.ath
days.after <- cumsum.r(1-restart, restart)
```

for days.before you need

```
rr <- rev(restart)
days.before <- -rev(cumsum.r(1-rr, rr))
```

(This does not put NAs, but you can use this cumsum.r for NAs too.)